# Tight binding model with Extended Huckel Approximation

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I've been reading Albright's Orbital Interactions in Chemistry. In the chapter on solids, he provided a general approach to find the band structure of a solid state system

[image]
[image]

Now if we are to model a one dimensional hydrogen chain, let $|1s(r)\rangle$ denote the $1s$ orbital centered at $r$. The band energy at each $k$ point will just be $e(k)=\frac{H_{11}(k)}{S_{11}(k)}$ according to the secular determinant. I then use a first neighbor interaction simplification, so $H_{11}(k)=\langle 1s(r)|H_{eff}|1s(r)\rangle+2\cdot\exp(ika)\langle 1s(r)|H_{eff}|1s(r-a)\rangle$ and $S_{11}=1+2\cdot\exp(ika)\langle1s(r)|1s(r-a)\rangle$.

It's worth noticing that assuming orthogonality of neighboring orbitals will set $S_{11}=1$, then $\langle 1s(r)|H_{eff}|1s(r-a) \rangle$ and $\langle 1s(r)|H_{eff}|1s(r)\rangle$ are just analogous to $\beta$ and $\alpha$ parameters in the simple Huckel model. But for the sake of realism I’m considering overlaps(the textbooks is also doing that) That is why the plots below show an asymmetric split with regard to hydrogen 1s ground state energy.

So far so good. I can even get a quick numerical estimate of $H_{11}$ using the extended Huckel approximation because then I just need to know the overlap integral between neighboring $1s$ orbitals. However, when I plot the result in Matlab it's different from the plot in the textbook:

[image: Calculation with lattice constant a=1.5 angstrom]

[image: Textbook plot]

Especially, the energy at the edge of the Brillouin zone is too positive. Anybody knows why that might happen? Thanks!

Comment: Since it's been a few days and you still haven't received an answer, I thought I might draw your attention to a dedicated computational chemical physics community that you might be interested in. There is a proposal for a Stack Exchange for Materials Modeling: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ODVjZmM2YzJmOTc0MzBkZDVkMTZmMTIzN2EyNmZmNTQyOWYyY2Y0YWFmNGYxNTQ2OTQzNmMwOWIyYjhhOTZjMhwblBomlTMtPu8EgXeAKtp-8dFsxghojkD0vBSe1wZl0. Perhaps you might consider supporting it if you think it would be useful for you!

Comment: Already there's some tight-binding questions there!

Comment: I don't know offhand, but I'd guess that you're using somewhat different parameters. If you tune $\beta$ the graph will change, so I suspect that's the main difference. Your approach looks fine to first approximation.